# SSH connects on local server through local network but doesn't connect while connecting through a different network

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

Please note, I tried finding about this issue a lot but wasn't able to, but still if I did miss out on some info on the internet then kindly respect the human error element, Thanks.

Before starting here is some info which may be required:

> Host OS: Debian 11 | Client OS: Ubuntu 21.04 | Router Model: Huawei EG8247H5 |  Software's Used: SSH and Open SSH

You may have understood the question from the title but let me elaborate more here, basically I have a old PC which I have tried to setup as a SSH server so I can connect to it locally and remotely as well. Now in this case when I connect to the host **locally** it works perfectly fine, do note here that I connect to the host locally through the locally assigned IP Address of the host.

But, in the case of connecting to the host through a different network (again note that in this case I use my IPV4 address to connect and I also have set IPV4 Port Forwarding rules on my router, here's an image of the settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqhZg.png). but when connecting, it gives the following result in this case: ***refer to Result Snippet 1***

**What I have tried until now:**

1. I tried to ping to my IPV4 address which worked fine
2. I tried using telnet which gives me the following output:
   ***refer to Result Snippet 2***
3. Tried to look on the internet for a potential solution but couldn't find something specific to this case.
4. I looked into detail on firewalls of both my host and client:

> In the host's case I am using minimal debian without and DE's so there is no firewall at the moment which would block any connections and on the clients side I checked it and no such IP or port is blocked.

***Posting all code/result snippets at the end as due to some reason I wasn't able to close the code box even after adding the ``` at the end.***

```
Result Snippet 1
================


~$ ssh -v username@IPAddress (Using default port 22 as I am in testing phase)
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-6ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to IPAddress [IPAddress] port 22.
debug1: connect to address IPAddress port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host IPAddress port 22: Connection timed out

Result Snippet 2
================


~$ telnet myIPAddress 22
Trying myIPAddress...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

Comment: A network map with IP addresses of devices would be useful here, as would a concise description of what "local" means here.  Have you checked you are not behind carrier grade NAT.  I'd do an iptables -vnl on the ssh server and check there was no blocking firewall rule, try running a tcpdump to see if packets are entering/leaving the server and attempt a remap from a port other then 22 in the router in case its bad firmware blocking port 22 on the router (which may be because the router is running an ssh server which is only accessible from the LAN)

Comment: By local I mean that I am connected to the same network as the SSH Server, in which case it works perfectly fine. Regarding the NAT, according to my findings it doesn't seem that there is any, I checked using traceroute and only my IPV4 is showing up. In tcpdump I don't see any ip's outside the local network (all ip's are from inside the network i.e: other device ip's etc.). Last option has worked!, I am surprised it was blocking port 22! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: To add a bit of info: Virtually all ISPs out there block 22, 25, 80 and 443 on their private home offers. They want to discourage companies buying a private home connection and then using these as their commercial internet connection, as private contracts are A LOT cheaper than commercial connections.

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I was facing. Luckily I contacted my ISP a couple days later after the above post, and surprisingly they unlocked all ports for me so now I can use all ports without any problem!